# Java. Использование переменной в двух разных кнопках(Jbutton)

Tags: java

```
String Math1 = "";
    B1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             String Math1 = "" + 1;
             label.setText(Math1);
        }
    });
    B2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String Math1 = "" + 2;
            label.setText(Math1);
        }
    });
```

B1 и B2 - кнопки
нужно, что бы при нажатии кнопок B1 и B2 к переменной Math (которая изначально равна ""), прибавлялось 1 и 2 соответственно
я думал сделать это через Math += ...
но для этого нужно использовать одну и ту же String переменную, которая будет создаваться в конструкторе/вне его
но такой способ невозможен потому что вне одного метода просто переменную "не видно"
Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы конструкторы видели переменную вне них самих?
Заранее извиняюсь за то, что я скорее всего часть после  addActionListener и до }); ошибочно называл конструктором.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         Math1 = Math1 + "1";
         label.setText(Math1);
    }
```

Comment: Подчеркивает красным Math1, хоть она и была задана ранее
Проблему решил методом создания массива String Math1

Comment: @Иван Я ничего не понял. Покажите больше кода.